# How do you use a TaskToken in .waitfortasktoken in Step function to callback in aws?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-step-functions

Step function code :

```
    {
      "StartAt": "Send message to SQS",
      "States": {
        "Send message to SQS": {
          "Type": "Task",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sqs:sendMessage.waitForTaskToken",
          "ResultPath": "$.List[0]",
          "HeartbeatSeconds": 180,
          "Parameters": {
            "QueueUrl": "https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/***********/test_poc2",
            "MessageBody": {
              "id.$": "$.id",
              "TaskToken.$": "$$.Task.Token"
              
            }
          },
          "Next": "checkOutput"
        },
        "checkOutput": {
          "Type": "Choice",
          "Choices": [
            {
              "Variable": "$.List[0]",
              "StringEquals": "completed",
              "Next": "SuccessHandler"
            },
            {
              "Variable": "$.List[0]",
              "StringEquals": "error",
              "Next": "ErrorHandler"
            }
          ]
        },
        "SuccessHandler": {
          "Type": "Succeed"
        },
        "ErrorHandler": {
          "Type": "Fail"
        }
      }
    }
```

Lambda Code:
`````python``````````````

```
import boto3
import json

step_functions = boto3.client('stepfunctions')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # extract token from the event
    print(event)
    data = event["Records"][0]["body"]
    task_token = json.loads(data)['TaskToken']
    print(task_token)
    step_functions.send_task_success(
        taskToken=task_token,
        output="\"error\""
    )
```

I have a Step function that uses .waitfortasktoken and calls SQS with a task token, internally calling Lambda. Lambda now returns the task toke. & everything works well for a first callback. After that, I receive an error in Lambda like this :

[ERROR] TaskTimedOut: An error occurred (TaskTimedOut) when calling the SendTaskSuccess operation: Task Timed Out: 'Provided task does not exist anymore.'

Would you please help me to resolve this error? I have been trying to google a lot but have not been able to fix it.

Comment: What is the code of your SFN?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question with the required code. Please have a look at it